# Retrieving Google plus user data by email

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I got the user email (not the ID) and i need its profile picture.
Is there a way to retrieve users profile data by email?
Something like that:

```
https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/my@email.com
```

Comment: If you can get user's email, so you can get user's picture link too by the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to lookup a Google+ user by email ([open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=64)). There is no static URL method for retrieving a profile image ([open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=66)).